# New Android Wear watches have 400x400 or 480x480 pixels, but Android Studio only support 320x320

Tags: android, wear-os

New Android Wear watches have 400x400 or 480x480 pixels, but Android Studio (layout design) only supports 320x320 pixels.

I don't physically have the new wear watches yet, therefore I cannot test if my drawing is rendered correctly in new watches, because I am using hardcoded dimensions in my code. It works well on my older watches like LG urbane, G watch and moto360 v1.

Will 320x320 layout being automatically upscaled to 400 or 480?

Comment: You can create a  Android Wear and custom screen resolution in Android Device Monitor?

Comment: sometimes the manufacturer releases some emulator skins or specifications for it. That needs a little bit google search, mostly you get something if you search for the manufacturer and developer like "samsung developers" ...for example, specifications for emulator skins from samsuing: http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/list.do?ct=CT350000